# Select rows based on value between 2 fields

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have table in SQL Server 2008:

```
CREATE TABLE [ValueDB](
[min_price] [float] NULL,
[max_price] [float] NULL
)
```

Now, I have this number 250, I need to select the rows where 250 is between  min_price and max_price

Comment: I see two types of answers have been posted - using inclusive or exclusive upper and lower bounds. You might want to say which is required, and also consider a suitable epsilon value for "exact" matches against floats, if required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something as simple as this:

```
SELECT * from ValueDB WHERE min_price < 250 AND max_price > 250
```

Answer (score 0):

Your pseudo-code description is 99% of what you need.

```
SELECT *
    FROM ValueDB
    WHERE 250 BETWEEN min_price AND max_price
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM ValueDB
WHERE 250 BETWEEN min_Price AND max_Price
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, this is all you would need to return all rows where the min price is below 250 and the max price is above 250.

```
SELECT *
FROM [ValueDB]
WHERE [min_price] < 250 AND [max_price] > 250
```

Comment: don't you mean `[max_price] > 250` ? :P

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from valuedb where 250 between min_price and max_price
```